# jquery append strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have to build html elements to make my webpage.

```
var container_item_data = $('<div>').attr('class', 'item_data');
var item_name = $('h4').append('weeee');

container_item_data.append(item_name, 'doooo');
$('#products').append(container_item_data);
```

But I only get 'doooo' string inside the container_item_data.
How can I make it work?

Comment: What else were you expecting?

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm guessing the OP expected `weeee doooo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the arrow brackets around the `h4` tag. Change your `var item_name` line to this:

```
var item_name = $('<h4>').append('weeee');
```

Here's a fiddle I made to help explain:

https://jsfiddle.net/qe1862ju/